# how to run node without getting stuck in the node command prompt

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I've installed node on my ubuntu virtual private server and I SSH into it.
I run

```
$nodejs index.js
```

but after running the file, I'm now stuck in the node command prompt and I can only get out by pressing ctrl-C. But doing that stops my nodejs server. 
I want to run my server and then go back to the shell and do other things. How do I do this?

Comment: run `nodejs index.js &` ... but please note that questions like this are *off topic* here

Answer (score 1):

Use PM2.  It is a process manager. You can do whatever after initiate this on the server. 
https://github.com/Unitech/pm2